# FullCalendar select multiple events in single filter

Tags: drop-down-menu, filter, fullcalendar, dropdown

I am using FullCalendar 3.1.0 plugin to show events. I was able to implement multiple events with a dropdown. But user is only able to select 1 option from a single dropdown filter. My goal is to give the opportunity to select multiple options in a each dropdown filter. I am using  dropdown. But when I hold down CTR and click on options, it only shows events for the first option in the list. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!-- Main view: Title and calendar -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h1 id="cal_title">Change Calendar</h1>
            <div class="search_bar">
                <ul id="menu">
                    Search By:
                    <li>
                        <select id="status_selector" multiple>
                            <option value="all" selected="selected">Status Types - All</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <select id="group_selector" multiple>
                            <option value="all" selected="selected">Group - All</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <select id="changeType_selector" multiple>
                            <option value="all" selected="selected">Type of Change - All</option>
                            <option value="6250">Emergency Change</option>
                            <option value="6882">Expedited Change</option>
                            <option value="6249">Normal Change</option>
                            <option value="9999">Standard Change</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <select id="downtime_selector" multiple>
                            <option value="all" selected="selected">Downtime - All</option>
                            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            <option value="No">No</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="calendar"></div>
            <div id="footer">To ensure optimal performance, only changes created in the past 90 days are shown. For changes older than 90 days please reference EasyVista. <br />If an issue has been found and/or you have a recommendation, please open a ticket for Service Request/Applications/EasyVista - Other Request, explaining the issue or recommendation.</div>
            <div id="version">SACC v2.0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        /* Find all the distinct STATUS_EN and place them into a dropdown list */
// This creates first 2 dropdown dynamically
        $.getJSON('json/events.json',function(json){
            var usedStatus = []; // Array to keep track of all STATUS_EN that have been seen
            var usedGroup = []; // Array to keep track of all group_selector that have been seen

            // For each object, store the status/group in predefined variables
            $.each(json, function(i,v){
                // If STATUS_EN has not been seen
                if (usedStatus.indexOf(v.STATUS_EN) == -1){ 
                    usedStatus.push(v.STATUS_EN); // Add STATUS_EN to usedStatus
                }
                // If responsible_group has not been seen
                if (usedGroup.indexOf(v.responsible_group) == -1){ 
                    usedGroup.push(v.responsible_group); // Add responsible_group to usedStatus
                }
            });

            // Sort both array variables in alphabetical order.
            usedStatus.sort();
            usedGroup.sort();

            // Create the dropdown
            usedStatus.forEach(function(value){
                if (value != undefined){ // If STATUS_EN is not undefined
                    $("#status_selector").append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>'); // Create an option for the dropdown list
                }
            });
            usedGroup.forEach(function(value){
                if (value != undefined){ // If responsible_group is not undefined
                    $("#group_selector").append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>'); // Create an option for the dropdown list
                }
            });

        });

        /* If end_date is null, return start_date */
        function isNull(end_date,start_date){
            if(end_date !== null){
                return end_date;
            } else {
                return start_date;
            }
        }

        /* Calendar structure */
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            /* Theme enabler */
            theme: false,

            /* Header description */
            header: {
                left: 'prev,today,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },

            /* Set the default view to Day */
            defaultView: 'basicWeek',

            /* Arrow stype (Used when theme is enabled) */
            themeButtonIcons: {
                prev: 'circle-triangle-w',
                next: 'circle-triangle-e'
            },

            /* Text to show in the button */
            buttonText: {
                today: 'Today',
                month: 'Month',
                week: 'Week',
                day: 'Day',
                list: 'Week List'
            },
            navLinks: true, // Can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: false, // Remove permission to move events
            eventLimit: true, // Allow "more" link when too many events
            businessHours: true, // grayout afterhours
            multiple: true,

            /* Function that allows user to click on event. */
            eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
                //set the values and open the modal

                $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
                $('#modalBody').html(event.text);
                $('#eventUrl').attr('href', event.url);
                $('#eventStatus').html("Status: " + event.STATUS_EN);
                $('#fullCalModal').modal('show');

                return false; // prevent from going to EasyVista right away
            },

            /* Function that shows description when hovering over event */
            eventMouseover: function (data, event, view) {
                tooltip = '<div class="tooltiptopicevent">'
                    + '<strong>Request Number:</strong> ' + data.RFC_NUMBER
                    + '<br /><strong>Status:</strong> ' + data.STATUS_EN 
                    + '<br /><strong>Start Date:</strong> ' + moment(data.start).format("MM/D, h:mm:ss a")
                    + '<br /><strong>End Date:</strong> ' + moment(isNull(data.end,data.start)).format("MM/D, h:mm:ss a")
                    + '<br /><strong>Description:</strong> ' + data.text + '</div>';
                $("body").append(tooltip);

                $(this).mousemove(function(event){
                    $(".tooltiptopicevent").position({
                        my: "left+3 bottom-3",
                        of: event,
                        collision: "flipfit"
                    });
                });
            },

            /* Hide description when mouse moves out */
            eventMouseout: function (data, event, view) {
                $(this).css('z-index', 8);
                $('.tooltiptopicevent').remove();
            },

            /* Feed in events from JSON file through PHP */
            events: {
                url: 'php/get-events.php'
            },


            /* Render the events */
            eventRender: function eventRender(event, element, view){
                return['all',event.STATUS_EN].indexOf($('#status_selector option:selected').val()) >= 0 
                    && ['all',event.responsible_group].indexOf($('#group_selector option:selected').val()) >= 0
                    && ['all',event.change_type].indexOf($('#changeType_selector option:selected').val()) >= 0
                    && ['all',event.downtime].indexOf($('#downtime_selector option:selected').val()) >= 0
            },

            /* Show status loading when loading */
            loading: function(bool) {
                $('#loading').toggle(bool);
            }
        });

        /* Call on fullCalendar after selection of dropdown option 
        $('#status_selector, #group_selector, #changeType_selector, #downtime_selector').change(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
            //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents'); // this allows the spinner to come up each time filter is changed.
        });*/
        /**/
        $('#status_selector, #group_selector, #changeType_selector, #downtime_selector').on('change',function(){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
        });


    });
```

Sample of how my .json file looks like:

```
[
{
    "start":  "2016-12-2T17:0:00",
    "end":  "2016-12-2T17:0:00",
    "title":  "12/2/2016 5:00 PM - group1",
    "url":  "https://sample.com",
    "text":  "some needed text",
    "description":  "description of event",
    "REQUEST_ID":  462820,
    "STATUS_EN":  "Open",
    "downtime":  "No",
    "change_type":  "9999",
    "responsible_group":  "group1",
    "RFC_NUMBER":  "C201612_09454"
},
{
    "start":  "2017-2-1T21:0:00",
    "end":  "2017-2-1T21:0:00",
    "title":  "2/1/2017 9:00 PM - group2",
    "url":  "https://samplesite.com",
    "text":  "some text",
    "description":  "description of event",
    "REQUEST_ID":  521157,
    "STATUS_EN":  "Closed",
    "downtime":  "No",
    "change_type":  "6250",
    "responsible_group":  "group2",
    "RFC_NUMBER":  "C201702_00976"
}
]
```

Comment: I am open for suggestions. Main goal is to have multiple dynamic drop down list that allows user to select multiple options from each drop down and return to FullCalendar through eventRender function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing .val() on a group of selected elements (e.g. your `$('#status_selector option:selected').val()`) will only return the value from the first matched element - as per the very first line of the docs: http://api.jquery.com/val/

So you need to loop through and check the values of all the selected options, and test for them individually. Something like this (untested):

```
          eventRender: function eventRender(event, element, view){
            var statusMatch = false;
            var statusArr = ['all',event.STATUS_EN];

            $('#status_selector option:selected').each(function(index, el)
            {
                if (statusArr.indexOf($(this).val()) > = 0) statusMatch = true;
            });

            var groupMatch = false;
            var groupArr = ['all',event.responsible_group];

            $('#group_selector option:selected').each(function(index, el)
            {
                if (groupArr.indexOf($(this).val()) > = 0) groupMatch = true;
            });

            var changeMatch = false;
            var changeArr = ['all',event.change_type];

            $('#changeType_selector option:selected').each(function(index, el)
            {
                if (changeArr.indexOf($(this).val()) > = 0) changeMatch = true;
            });

            var downtimeMatch = false;
            var downtimeArr = ['all',event.downtime];

            $('#downtime_selector option:selected').each(function(index, el)
            {
                if (downtimeArr.indexOf($(this).val()) > = 0) downtimeMatch = true;
            });

            return (statusMatch && groupMatch && changeMatch && downtimeMatch);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, @ADyson, this got be going on where I wanted. I tried a few ways but can't figure out how I can loop through and return the indexes for each filter. 
I tried getting the values:
var typ = $( "#changeType_selector" ).val() || [];
then in return, looping through:
&& ['all',event.change_type].indexOf(typ[0]) >= 0 if(typ.length > 1){for(var i=1; i<typ.length; i++){['all',event.change_type].indexOf(typ[i]) >= 0}}
But this does not work. Any suggestions?

Or I need to figure how I can modify FullCalendar javascript code to accept an array of indexes.

Comment: `$( "#changeType_selector" ).val() || []` makes no sense. It will give you either the first selected option, or an empty array. Neither of these is any good to you. Wait a little bit and I'll try and write a suggested solution.

Comment: ok, I've added some code. I didn't have time to test it, but hopefully you get the idea. You have to loop through each of the selected values for each dropdown and check each one individually against the relevant property of the event.

Comment: Great, thanks. It worked great after I removed the space between > and =.
Again, thanks. I have been working on this for few days now.